# How to set the parent div width to match the a/img?

Tags: html, css, image, division

I want to have 4 images in a line, equally spaced. Then when the screen size is of a particular resolution, i want 2 images to drop to the line below.

Setting the 4 images in a line, equally spaced is the easy part. I'm struggling to get two of the images on the line below. My thought is to wrap two images in a div and do this twice. So there is two divs, with 2 images in them each. When the screen resolution is large, set the divs to `inline-blocks`. Then when the resolution drops too low, set the divs to block.

**The issue:** The div's width will not match the width of the two images. Instead, the divs span across the entire width of its parent div.

How do I fix this? Or is there a different way that's better?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shocker33/a212z7qs/1/)

```css
.Containter{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.Sections{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.Sections>a{
    border: 1px solid brown;
}

.Photo{
    width: 20%;
    height: auto%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;*/
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="Containter">
    <div class="Sections">
        <a href="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"><img class="Photo" src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"/></a>

        <a href="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"><img class="Photo" src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"/></a>
    </div>

    <div class="Sections">
        <a href="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"><img class="Photo" src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"/></a>

        <a href="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"><img class="Photo" src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use media query to achieve what you want like this:

Here a working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/rotjomza/) to play with

```css
.Containter {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.Sections {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.Sections>a {
    border: 1px solid brown;
}
.Photo {
    width: 20%;
    height: auto%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /*margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;*/
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) { /*change to desired resolution*/
    .Photo {
        width: 45%; /*change to desired width*/
    }
```

```html
<div class="Containter">
    <div class="Sections"> <a href="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"><img class="Photo" src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"/></a>
 <a href="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"><img class="Photo" src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"/></a>
 <a href="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"><img class="Photo" src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"/></a>
 <a href="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"><img class="Photo" src="https://www.wonderplugin.com/wp-content/plugins/wonderplugin-lightbox/images/demo-image0.jpg"/></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

[Check out this for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: This isn't what i'm looking for. I want to set the div to the width of the two images plus a little margin. Not, set the image widths to fill the div.

Where each photo's width is set to 20% with the margin left and right that i've commented out, the 4 images line up perfectly for the desired width when the screen resolution is large.

Eg. [JSFiddle before i put in the two divs containing two images each](http://jsfiddle.net/Shocker33/a212z7qs/3/)

The issue with this is that i don't want the top line to contain 3 images and the bottom only 1 for any screen resolution.

Comment: Actually, i take my comment back. I understand what it does now. 
Cracking. It does the job. Cheers.

Comment: I'm glad to help you.